# Does H. pylori have paracellular activity?

Tags: microbiology

I know that it has transcellular activity i.e. it can pass through neighbouring cells.
However, I am not completely sure if it does not have paracellular activity, see [this](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC108731/):

> H. pylori did not induce any modification of the paracellular pathway
>   (R = 148 ± 10 versus 174 ± 16 Ω · cm2; JNa = 4.16 ± 0.44 versus 3.51 ±
>   0.41 μEq/h · cm2; JMan = 0.081 ± 0.01 versus 0.058 ± 0.009 μmol/h · cm2), nor did it modify J3H-HRP (2,201 ± 255 versus 2,110 ± 210 ng/h ·
>   cm2 for H. pylori-infected and control cells, respectively). However,
>   in the presence of H. pylori, we observed a significant increase in
>   JHRPi (520 ± 146 versus 171 ± 88 ng/h · cm2). This effect was not
>   dependent of the cag status of the strain and was not reproduced by
>   the sonicates or the culture supernatants.

**Is there any evidence that Helicobacter pylori has paracellular activity?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found no evidence for paracellular movement.

Some notes of mine

> - Mucinase $\to$ lophotrichous flagella $\to$ Transcellular (actin fibrils, tails) movement
> - ICF Vacuolating cytotoxin (VacA) $\to$ altered T-cell function $\to$
>     damages epithelial cells, disrupts tight junctions and causes
>     apoptosis.

I think the latter point makes transcellular momevment possible.
I see no way how paracellular movement would be possible.